# Spring Boot / FeignClient: POST Json Body

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I currently try to implement a POST call to a backend which requires me to POST json as body.

Now I'm facing the issue that Feign does not pass the annotated Body to the backend but only empty data.

As soon as I add a single `@Param` or a Map, those values are passed and the client works fine.

To increase readability I'd prefer to annotate the method with the Body and get the values from my config instead of passing them as method parameter.

The following example should work according to the Feign Documentation:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Headers("Content-Type: " + MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Body("%7B\n"
  + "  \"user\": \"${logintoken.user}\",\n"
  + "  \"pwd\": \"${logintoken.password}\",\n"
  + "%7D")
String getLoginToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug:

https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/issues/503

Try Unirest if you need body. Not declarative, rather a builder.

Comment: argg :-( Thanks for the answer. I don't want to replace the client as it's already used in other parts of the project, seems like I need another approach (e.g. using a Map<String,?> as @RequestBody seems to do the job.